# Creating a dynamic JSON body from a previous REST call

Tags: json, powershell

I'm working on a script to modify the security of existing objects via API. I can easily grab the objects, and the list of users/groups assigned to them. However, I need to parse through this data, and add any users/groups that don't match to a new JSON body to be sent back in a POST request. I've built 2 functions for this. One for creating the JSON body, the other for adding to the remove section of the JSON body. However, it's not adding the id/type to the remove section as I would expect, as the remove section of the JSON remains empty after each iteration.

What am I missing here?

```
function Build-JsonBody {
    param (
        [string]$defaultSecurity,
        [array]$include,
        [array]$remove
    )

    $jsonBody = @{
        "default_security" = $defaultSecurity
        "include"          = $include
        "remove"           = $remove
    }

    return $jsonBody
}

function Add-ToRemoveSection {
    param (
        [ref]$removeSection,
        [string]$id,
        [string]$type
    )

    $itemToRemove = @{
        "id"   = $id
        "type" = $type
    }

    $removeSection.Value += $itemToRemove
}

Write-Host "Finding all workspaces with Matter #$matter_num..."
$ws_search_url = $baseurl + "/work/api/v2/customers/$customer_id/libraries/ABC/workspaces?custom2=$matter_num"
$ws_resp = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ws_search_url -Headers $header -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
$ws_results = $ws_resp.data.results

# For each workspace returned, look at the list of users, groups, and default security
foreach($ws in $ws_results){
    $id = $ws.id
    $sec_search_url = $baseurl + "/work/api/v2/customers/$customer_id/libraries/ABC/workspaces/ABC!164/security"
    $sec_resp = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $sec_search_url -Headers $header -Method Get -ContentType "application/json"
    $sec_results = $sec_resp.data.results
    $jsonBody = Build-JsonBody -defaultSecurity "private" -include @(@{ "id" = "ADMIN_USERS"; "access_level" = "full_access"; "type" = "group" }) -remove @()

    # Iterate through the source data
    foreach ($item in $sec_results) {
        if ($item.id -ne "ADMIN_USERS") {
            # For "user" type, add to the "remove" section
            Add-ToRemoveSection -removeSection ([ref]$jsonBody.remove) -id $item.id -type $item.type
        }
        }
    }         
    
    #Convert body to JSON
    $jsonBodyJson = $jsonBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
    Write-Host $jsonBodyJson
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for the issue you're experiencing is that arrays are collections of a fixed size and when you do `+=` on an array, PowerShell creates a new array and copies all its contents together with the item you're adding. In your function, even if not using `[ref]`, you're assigning the variable `$removeSection` the same reference as `$jsonBody.remove` but, when adding a new item `+=`, that reference is lost and `$removeSection` is assigned a new array.

```
$arr = @()
& { param($i) $i += 1 } -i $arr
$arr # nothing
```

Your workaround could be to pass the hashtable that holds your array (`$jsonBody`) as argument:

```
$jsonbody = @{ remove = @() }
& { param($i) $i.remove += 1 } $jsonBody
$jsonBody

# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# remove                         {1}
```

Or, you could use a [collection that allows you to add items to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0):

```bash
$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]::new()
& { param($i) $i.Add(1) } $list
$list # 1
```

If using a `List<T>` your functions could be:

```bash
function Build-JsonBody {
    param (
        [string] $defaultSecurity,
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]] $include,
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]] $remove
    )

    @{
        'default_security' = $defaultSecurity
        'include'          = $include
        'remove'           = $remove
    }
}

function Add-ToRemoveSection {
    param (
        [System.Collections.Generic.List[hashtable]] $removeSection,
        [string] $id,
        [string] $type
    )

    $removeSection.Add(@{
        'id'   = $id
        'type' = $type
    })
}
```

Then, it should work fine:

```bash
$jsonBody = Build-JsonBody -defaultSecurity 'private' -include @() -remove @()
Add-ToRemoveSection -removeSection $jsonBody['remove'] -id 'foo' -type 'bar'
Add-ToRemoveSection -removeSection $jsonBody['remove'] -id 'baz' -type '123'
$jsonBody['remove']

# Name                           Value
# ----                           -----
# id                             foo
# type                           bar
# id                             baz
# type                           123
```

There is also an even easier, simpler approach, and that is to not use functions at all, you could just manipulate `$jsonBody` in the loop and assign to the `remove` key the result from the inner loop:

```bash
foreach ($ws in $ws_results) {
    # some code goes before this
    $jsonBody = Build-JsonBody # .....

    # Iterate through the source data
    $toRemove = foreach ($item in $sec_results) {
        if ($item.id -ne 'ADMIN_USERS') {
            @{
                id   = $item.id
                type = $item.type
            }
        }
    }

    $jsonBody['remove'] = @($toRemove)
}
```